# Parse json to ruby object

Tags: ruby, json

In ruby how can i parse a json to an array of objects?
Example: i have 2 classes:

```
class Person 
  attr_accessor :name, :address, :email, :address
end
```

And:

```
class Address
  attr_accessor :street, :city, :state, :person
end
```

When i make a request i get the following json:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 9111316,
      "name": "Mason Lee",
      "email": "normanodonnell@biospan.com",
      "address": {
        "state": "American Samoa",
        "street": "Cameron Court",
        "city": "Wakulla"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 500019,
      "name": "Stella Weeks",
      "email": "hansenwhitfield@candecor.com",
      "address": {
        "state": "Nevada",
        "street": "Lake Street",
        "city": "Wacissa"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This `json` should be parsed into an array of `Person`.
For now i'm doing:

```
#json gem
require 'json'

#...
#parse the json and get the 'data'
parsed_json = JSON.parse json
json_data = parsed_json['data']

objects = Array.new
if json_data.kind_of?(Array)

  #add each person
  json_data.each { |data|
    current_person = Person.new
    data.each { |k, v|
      current_person.send("#{k}=", v)
    }
    objects.push(current_person)
  }
end

#return the array of Person
objects
```

I have a lot of objects like the above example and do this parse manually is not desirable. **There is an automated way to do this?**

By "automated way" i mean something like in `java` with [jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Person> myObjects = mapper.readValue(json, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Person.class));
```

Comment: Try searching the web for keywords like "ruby json serialization", e.g. https://github.com/harmoni/json-serializer, https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers, etc

Comment: I wrote a gem to do this though you can't specify the class at the moment, they are generated dynamically -- https://github.com/allcentury/classy_json

Comment: @maerics In my case i need to deserialize the json, and i'm still searching about it

Comment: @Anthony it works fine. I've not found your gem in any repository, are you planning to publish your gem soon? The unique problem in my case is that i need specify the class. Anyway thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just make the method yourself? Example:

```
require 'json'
def parse_json_to_class_array(data,root_node,to_klass)
  json_data = JSON.parse(data)[root_node]
  if json_data.is_a?(Array)
    objects = json_data.map do |item|
      klass = to_klass.new
      item.each { |k,v| klass.public_send("#{k}=",v) }
      klass
    end
  end 
  objects ||= []
end
```

Then for your example you could call it like so

```
json ="{\"data\":[
          {\"id\":9111316,
           \"name\":\"Mason Lee\",
           \"email\":\"normanodonnell@biospan.com\",
           \"address\":{
              \"state\":\"American Samoa\",
              \"street\":\"Cameron Court\",
              \"city\":\"Wakulla\"
            }
          },
           {\"id\":500019,
            \"name\":\"Stella Weeks\",
            \"email\":\"hansenwhitfield@candecor.com\",
            \"address\":{
               \"state\":\"Nevada\",
               \"street\":\"Lake Street\",
               \"city\":\"Wacissa\"
             }
           }
         ]
       }"
class Person 
  attr_accessor :id, :name,:email, :address
end


parse_json_to_class_array(json,'data',Person) 
#=>[#<Person:0x2ede818 @id=9111316, @name="Mason Lee", @email="normanodonnell@biospan.com", @address={"state"=>"American Samoa", "street"=>"Cameron Court", "city"=>"Wakulla"}>, 
    #<Person:0x2ede7a0 @id=500019, @name="Stella Weeks", @email="hansenwhitfield@candecor.com", @address={"state"=>"Nevada", "street"=>"Lake Street", "city"=>"Wacissa"}>]
```

Obviously you can expand this implementation to support single objects as well as overwrite `Person#address=` to perform the same operation and turn the address `Hash` into an `Address` object as well but this was not shown in your example so I did not take it this far in my answer.

A more dynamic example can be found [Here](https://gist.github.com/carcogap/11c720fa3bf65aecdd50)

Comment: thank you for the snippet, since i've not found any gem to do this, looks like it will be better make the method as you said

Comment: @Victor in that case I have taken the time to create a more dynamic version that will also create the `Address` object and added it to the end of my post.

Comment: I'll have to change some things to fit other scenarios, but it's a good base to start :) thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can initialize the Person with the hash:

```
json_data = JSON.parse(json)['data']
json_data.map do |data|
  Person.new data
end

class Person 
  attr_accessor :name, :email, :address

  def initialize params
    params.each { |k,v| klass.public_send("#{k}=",v) }
  end 
end
```

If you want to choose the class dynamically, you can use:

```
json_data.map do |data|
  klass = 'Person'
  klass.get_const.new data
```

Comment: The question does not really say anthing about specifying the class dynamically: `List<Person> myObjects`. Also, the class is not specified in the JSON.

Comment: very well i have removed my comment. I still prefer your pattern and have added it to my gist. What I actually meant is that he did not want to have to keep writing `json_data.map` and then having to specify the the class name in the loop. The OP is looking for a more automatic construct to handle this where data is passed with it's conversion class and then returned appropriately.

Comment: It would be simple to create a method out of the code that accepts a class param. However, it seems to me that doesn't really make sense because in order for it to be "automatic" the class would need to be specified in the JSON.